# How to select multiple areas in containment using jQuery UI draggable

Tags: html, jquery-ui

Hi i want to select multipe areas in containment using jQuery UI draggable while usinf drag and drop. I have used `containment:["#area1","#area2","#area3"]`, also made single class with name area and applied to all divs but still not working, even tried `containment: '#area1, #area2, #area3'` but still not working. Its taking only the first container only. Please suggest

Comment: How does multiple containment work? Unless the boundaries intersect, just make the largest bounding box the container.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the ui containment options like following:

```
containment:'selector1, selector2,selector3...'
```