# jQueryUI: how to restrict droppable area to multiple divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

It feels like the question is already answered:

- [How to select multiple areas in containment using jQuery UI draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717715/how-to-select-multiple-areas-in-containment-using-jquery-ui-draggable)
- [Set more than one containment in jQuery Draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564317/set-more-than-one-containment-in-jquery-draggable)

I have 3 timelines and some draggable elements to place there. For some reason I cannot get it to work. This is the syntax I'm using: `containment: ".timeline1, .timeline2, .timeline3"`

[image]

```js
$(function() {
  $(".timeline1, .timeline2, .timeline3").droppable();

  $(".event").draggable({
    containment: ".timeline1, .timeline2, .timeline3"
  });
});
```

```css
.timeline1, .timeline2, .timeline3 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 3px dashed gray;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.event {
  height: 40px;
  background: gray;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<div class="timeline1"></div>
<div class="timeline2"></div>
<div class="timeline3"></div>

<div class="event">dance</div>
<div class="event">sleep</div>
<div class="event">eat</div>
```

---

Update found in the docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment

> The draggable element will be contained to the bounding box of the first element found by the selector

Question is still valid, I'd really like to know how to restrict droppable area to multiple divs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do this with the containment option, but you can use snap, snapMode and revert to accomplish what you're trying to do.

I'd add a common class like `timeline-droppable` to your timeline elements to make it easier:

```
<div class="timeline1 timeline-droppable"></div>
<div class="timeline2 timeline-droppable"></div>
<div class="timeline3 timeline-droppable"></div>
```

Use the snap option to snap to your droppable timelines. Use the revert option to determine whether the draggable was dropped in a valid droppable:

```
$(function() {
    $(".timeline-droppable").droppable();

    $(".event").draggable({
        snap: ".timeline-droppable",
        snapMode: "inner",
        revert:  function(droppedElement) {
            var validDrop = droppedElement && droppedElement.hasClass("timeline-droppable");
            return !validDrop;
        } 
    });
});
```

Of course you'll need to tweak the CSS to make your event elements fit nicely inside your timeline elements.

Comment: Awesome! Combination of ```span```, ```snapMode``` and ```revert``` does the job :)